# Disable selectAll in Android

Tags: android

I need to disable copy,paste,selectAll,etc.
And I wrote editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(actionModeCallback);
But when the cursor stop in somewhere,click here with water drop, selectAll option appeared.

so I add editText.setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback(actionModeCallback);
and repeat the previous operation, selectAll option dont appear.
Why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:longClickable="false"
```

or

```
etUsername.setLongClickable(false);
```

Comment: thanks for you comment, I add this code, but my question is why setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback can let me click water drop dont appear selectAll